How can I use specific cells in a Google sheets range?
I'm creating a Discord bot. Whenever I use the command that this is linked to it works. However it displays all the data in all cells in the set range. How do I get a specific cell out of the range and use it?
The way I've been doing it is by replacing the range to a specific cell, but I feel like that isn't the most practical way to do this.
Can anyone help? I'm pretty new to JS so any tips would be greatly appreciated.
async function readCerts() {
  const sheets = google.sheets({
    version: 'v4',
    auth
  });
  const spreadsheetId = 'myIdHere';
  const range = 'Overview!B5:H60';
  try {
    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId,
      range
    });
    const rows = response.data.values;
    return rows;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error', error);
  }
}


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result How can I use specific cells in a Google sheets range? and How do I get a specific cell out of the range and use it?. Can I ask you about the details of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

@Tanaike I have a google spreadsheet linked to my bot, the cells that are in the range is B5-H60, I just want to use E20, F30, G50, and C10 how would i get that cells information?

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

@Tanaike If i wanted to get the response of each one separately how would that be done? Instead of the response being all together.

For example im trying to use them in here when i create an embed in discord
{
name: Total DAs: ,
value: ${E20},
inline: false,
},
{
name: Total Selections Hosted: ,
value: ${F30},
inline: false,
},
{
name: New Recruits: ,
value: ${G50},
inline: false,
},
{
name: S2 Mini Events: ,
value: ${C10},
inline: false,
},

Thank you for replying. About @Tanaike If i wanted to get the response of each one separately how would that be done? Instead of the response being all together., in my answer, rows is an object. So, you can retrieve each value using the key. For examele, if you want the value of "E20", you can retrieve as rows["E20"]. If you retrieve the value from rows as pcc, the value of "E20" can be retrieved as pcc["E20"]. If this was not your expected result, I apologize.

Or, as another approach, from your showing script, if you use const pcc = await readCerts();, how about modifying it to const {E20, F30, G50, C10} = await readCerts();. By this, you can directly use the values as the variables of E20, F30, G50, C10.

@Tanaike Aw man, Thank you so much! You helped me out a lot!

Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

@Tanaike, Ive actually ran into one more issue. When the cell is empty it gives me an error, is there any way to fix this? error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

About your new question Ive actually ran into one more issue. When the cell is empty it gives me an error, is there any way to fix this? error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'), I added one more modification point. Please confirm it.

@Tanaike It works! Thanks again!

From your following reply,

I have a google spreadsheet linked to my bot, the cells that are in the range is B5-H60, I just want to use E20, F30, G50, and C10 how would i get that cells information?

I understood your actual expected result as follows.

You want to retrieve the cell values from the cells E20, F30, G50, and C10 using Sheets API.

In this case, how about using "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet"? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
In this modification, your function readCerts is modified. In this modification, in order to retrieve the cell values from E20, F30, G50, and C10, "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet" is used.
async function readCerts() {
  const spreadsheetId = "myIdHere";
  const sheetName = "Overview";
  const cells = ["E20", "F30", "G50", "C10"];

  const ranges = cells.map((c) => `'${sheetName}'!${c}`);
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
  try {
    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({ spreadsheetId, ranges });
    const rows = response.data.valueRanges.reduce((o, { values }, i) => ((o[cells[i]] = values[0][0]), o), {});
    return rows;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("error", error);
  }
}


When this script is run, the value of rows is as follows.
{
  "E20": "cell value of E20",
  "F30": "cell value of F30",
  "G50": "cell value of G50",
  "C10": "cell value of C10"
}


When you want to retrieve only values in order of ["E20", "F30", "G50", "C10"] as a 1-dimensional array, please modify const rows = response.data.valueRanges.reduce((o, { values }, i) => ((o[cells[i]] = values[0][0]), o), {}); as follows.
const rows = response.data.valueRanges.map(({ values }) => values[0][0]);



Note:

In this modification, it supposes that your client can access the Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

Reference:

Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet

Added:
About your following new question,

Ive actually ran into one more issue. When the cell is empty it gives me an error, is there any way to fix this? error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

In this case, please modify the above script as follows.
From:
const rows = response.data.valueRanges.reduce((o, { values }, i) => ((o[cells[i]] = values[0][0]), o), {});

To:
const rows = response.data.valueRanges.reduce((o, { values = [[""]] }, i) => ((o[cells[i]] = values[0][0]), o), {});

or
const rows = response.data.valueRanges.reduce((o, { values }, i) => ((o[cells[i]] = values ? values[0][0] : ""), o), {});

